# Tensorflow Hub Image Modules: Clarity on Preprocessing and Output values

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-slim, tensorflow-hub

Many thanks for support!
I currently use TF Slim - and TF Hub seems like a very useful addition for transfer learning. However the following things are not clear from the documentation:
**1. Is preprocessing done implicitly?** Is this based on "trainable=True/False" parameter in constructor of module?

```
module = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_v3/feature_vector/1", trainable=True)
```

When I use Tf-slim I use the preprocess method:

```
inception_preprocessing.preprocess_image(image, img_height, img_width, is_training)
```

**2.How to get access to AuxLogits for an inception model?** Seems to be missing:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow as tf

img = tf.random_uniform([10,299,299,3])
module = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_v3/feature_vector/1", trainable=True)
outputs = module(dict(images=img), signature="image_feature_vector", as_dict=True)
```

The output is

```
dict_keys(['InceptionV3/Mixed_6b', 'InceptionV3/MaxPool_5a_3x3', 'InceptionV3/Mixed_6c', 'InceptionV3/Mixed_6d', 'InceptionV3/Mixed_6e', 'InceptionV3/Mixed_7a', 'InceptionV3/Mixed_7b', 'InceptionV3/Conv2d_2a_3x3', 'InceptionV3/Mixed_7c', 'InceptionV3/Conv2d_4a_3x3', 'InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3', 'InceptionV3/global_pool', 'InceptionV3/MaxPool_3a_3x3', 'InceptionV3/Conv2d_2b_3x3', 'InceptionV3/Conv2d_3b_1x1', 'default', 'InceptionV3/Mixed_5b', 'InceptionV3/Mixed_5c', 'InceptionV3/Mixed_5d', 'InceptionV3/Mixed_6a'])
```

Answer (score 2):

These are excellent questions; let me try to give good answers also for readers less familiar with TF-Slim.

**1. Preprocessing is not done by the module**, because it is a lot about your data, and not so much about the CNN architecture within the module. The module only handles transforming input values from the canonical [0,1] range into whatever the pre-trained CNN within the module expects.

Lengthy rationale: Preprocessing of images for CNN training usually consists of decoding the input JPEG (or whatever), selecting a (reasonably large) random crop from it, random photometric and geometric transformations (distort colors, flip left/right, etc.), and resizing to the common image size for a batch of training inputs. The TensorFlow Hub modules that implement https://tensorflow.org/hub/common_signatures/images leave all of that to your code around the module.

The primary reason is that the suitable random transformations depend a lot on your training task, but not on the architecture or trained state weights of the module. For example, color distortions will help if you classify cars vs dogs, but probably not for ripe vs unripe bananas, and so on.

Also, a batch of images that have been decoded but not yet cropped/resized are hard to represent as a single tensor (unless you make it a 1-D tensor of encoded strings, but that brings other problems, such as breaking backprop into module inputs for advanced uses).

Bottom line: The Python code using the module needs to do image preprocessing (except scaling values), for example, as in https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py

The slim preprocessing methods conflate the dataset-specific random transformations (tuned for Imagenet!) with the re-scaling to the architecture's value range (which the Hub module does for you). That means they are not directly applicable here.

**2. Indeed, auxiliary heads are missing from the initial set of modules** published under tfhub.dev/google/..., but I expect them to work fine for re-training anyways.

More details: Not all architectures have auxiliary heads, and even the original Inception paper says their effect was "relatively minor" [Szegedy&al. 2015; §5]. Using an image feature vector module for a custom classification task would burden the module consumer code with checking for aux features and, if found, putting aux logits and a loss term on top.

This complication did not seem to pull its weight, but more experiments might refute that assessment. (**Please share** in a GitHub issue if you know of any.)

For now, the only way to put an aux head onto https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_v3/feature_vector/1 is to copy&paste some lines from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/inception_v3.py (search "Auxiliary head logits") and apply that to the "Inception_V3/Mixed_6e" output that you saw.

**3. You didn't ask, but:** For training, the module's documentation recommends to pass hub.Module(..., tags={"train"}), or else batch norm operates in inference mode (and dropout, if the module had any).

Hope this explains how and why things are.

Arno (from the TensorFlow Hub developers)

Comment: Many thanks for the awesomely detailed response. Would you be so kind to expand on this "Also, a batch of images that have been decoded but not yet cropped/resized are hard to represent as a single tensor (unless you make it a 1-D tensor of encoded strings, but that brings other problems, such as breaking backprop into module inputs for advanced uses)."

Comment: The latent assumptions here are that (a) your dataset has images of different sizes, and (b) you want to run the module on batches of N images each (for speed, and for the benefit of batch norm).

1) Why not make the module accept a tensor of shape [N] and dtype string with some encoding of the images? Imagine using the module as part of a model that extracts/generates the input in some way. You couldn't train it end-to-end, because encoding/decoding the module input would break backprop.

(tbc)

Comment: (cont'd)

2) Why not put all images into one tensor of shape [N,H,W,C] and leave some entries unused? This would require passing extra information about the actually used sizes and dissecting the input accordingly. That would be cumbersome and yield an inefficient TF graph in the end.

--- But that's all secondary. The primary reason is, as stated above: The data augmentation that happens as part of preprocessing has to depend on the dataset, not the CNN architecture within the module, so it makes perfect sense to leave it to the module consumer (possibly using library code).

Comment: Many thanks again - followup question on weight decay: In tf-slim default weight decay is set by inception_arg_scope as weight_decay=0.00004. I assume this would be set to 1.0 currently so this can be handled externally. Is that correct?

Comment: hub.Module(..., trainable=True) brings in the REGULARIZATION_LOSSES collection of the module's graph, in this case, the weight decay terms with the coefficient set originally in the slim code. If you do the usual thing and include the result of tf.get_regularization_losses() in the loss passed to the optimizer, then all the losses from the trainable module(s) in your model are included.

Comment: So I understand that the l2 weight decay is hardcoded when we access the model through tf-hub - is that correct? I believe this is an hyperparameter that should be available for end users to be able to fine tune. Do you agree? Possible ways to implement (a) Add an argument to allow passing this to the model (b) hardcode weight decay as 1.0 in the code - and the uses can scale it along with all regularization losses together. e.g.  `(reg_loss = l2_reg_const * sum(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)))`

Comment: Yes, it would be good for expert users to take regularization strength into their own hands. Would you mind filing a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/new), esp. if you have experiments underlining the importance to do so? For now, as a workaround, you could manually check what `hub.Module(...)` adds to `tf.get_collection_ref(REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)`, take those out and add them back scaled up.

Comment: Thank you again - I will open a github issue. (a) I'm not sure how to manually check - i was unable to find the code where this is added - can you pls elaborate? (b) A question on design of the API: We get "trainable" parameter - why do we need the tags (train/test)? If trainable is True, then execute the train graph - else the test graph. What am i missing?

Comment: (a) Just inspect the list tf.get_collection_ref(REGULARIZATION_LOSSES) before and after.
(b) Graph versions will likely be useful for more fine-grained distinctions (e.g., fine-tuning with frozen batch norm or not; or GPU/TPU-specific optimizations), so I'm shy to simply equate `trainable <->["train"]` and `not trainable <-> set()`.

Comment: Many thanks arnoegw. I have raised a new github issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/63